# Start react-create-app and Electron.js with one NPM command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, electron, npm-scripts

I have simple custom starter pack `react-create-app` and `Electron.js`.
I have added to package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "electron": "electron .",
    "start": "cross-env BROWSER=none react-scripts start",
....
```

and I can start Electron with `npm run electron` and React with - `npm start`.

What I want is to start React and Electron just with one command like: `npm run both`.

I have tried:

```
"both": "\"npm start\" \"npm run electron \"",
```

but I am getting an error in a log file:

> Exit status 1 node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
>   - nothing specific

I have tried and:

```
    "start": "npm run electron . && cross-env BROWSER=none react-scripts start",
```

, but this starts the Electron, when I close it, it start the React app.

Again error:

```
"electron": "electron .",
"start": "cross-env BROWSER=none react-scripts start",
"both": "\"npm run electron\" \"npm run start\"",
```

I don't know, how to start `react-create-app` and `Electron` with just one NPM command ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider utilizing [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).

1. `cd` to your project directory and run the following command to install it:

   ```
   npm i -D concurrently
   ```
2. Then redefine the `both` script in the `scripts` section of your *package.json* as follows:

   ```json
   "both": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run electron\""
   ```

   or the slightly shortened equivalent:

   ```json
   "both": "concurrently \"npm:start\" \"npm:electron\""
   ```